# Django Admin render TimeField as 12 hour time

Tags: django, django-admin

In the Django admin I have it accepting input in 12 hour time inputs but when I return to it on the admin it is just turning that into a 24 hour time and leaving it in that field. Is there a way I can have it displayed in the admin as a 12 hour time input?

```
class ShowDateAdminForm(ModelForm):

time = forms.TimeField(input_formats=['%I:%M %p'])

class Meta:
    model = ShowDates
    exclude = ('show_slug',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`formfield_overrides`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) when you create your admin instance e.g.

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.forms import widgets

from myapp.models import MyModel

class ShowDateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TimeField: {'widget': widgets.TimeInput(format='%I:%M %p')},
    }
```